# Where can I find help with Mishnayos learning?

Tags: mishna

I signed up to learn Mishnayos for someone's Neshama, but then I pushed it off for too long. I now only have less than a week and I don't know if I'll be able to finish on time. 
I have 2 questions.
1. Is there any website where I can go with people who can help me complete the learning on time?
2. Are there any Heters to make the learning easier for me? (ex. Just reading the Mishnayos without understanding them?)

Comment: The Art Scroll Mishnayos have English translation.

Comment: @sabbahillel I know. My question is if I can read through the Hebrew quickly without understanding it.

Comment: That is why I suggested the Art Scroll. The English will allow you to understand the Hebrew and read through almost as fast.

Comment: @sabbshillel I know, but a lot of Mishnayos are hard to understand, so it would take me a while. I'm wondering if I could just read through and be done with it.

Comment: Sorry, I would not dare give a yes answer to that which means that I cannot answer at all, since I would not be objective.

Comment: 3 comments: 1. Sounds like Halacha Lemaaseh 2. try http://www.chevrahlomdeimishnah.org/learning-lzecher-nishmas/EXTENSIVE-MISHNAH-STUDY or googling this, there are probably a lot of people who do this for pay. 3. What about putting up the Maseches/Masechtos and seeing if MYers can help you finish in time?

Comment: Re #2 - *Lefum tza'ara agra* (from Pirkei Avot). The reward is according to the effort. In other words, you don't need a heter of any type. You're rewarded according to the effort you placed into it. Things get in the way of life - that happens. Try what you can, and, perhaps, a bit more effort, again, according to what you can do.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Re suggestion #3 - How do you propose this to be done on MY?

Comment: @DanF in comments or questions, he could just list the Perakim remaining and the name of the person, and see if anyone would take one or two to help out.  I'm not sure this would be a good site policy to allow in general, I'm just saying if someone here asked for something like that, I would probably do a perek for someone's Neshama rather than researching an answer about something else random (if it was just a one time thing).  But, In, Hachi Nami, if I was a mod, I'd try to distance this from the site as much as possible.

Comment: If you did want to recruit people from Mi Yodeya, I'd recommend [chat]. But there are probably better fora for this kind of thing.

Comment: Perhaps the Judaism subreddit on reddit? Post there and see who volunteers.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.chevrahlomdeimishnah.org/ is a website that you can contact to help you finish Mishnayos.

Hat tip to רבות מחשבות.